# How to load webpage related files into web view in android?

Tags: android

I want to load a webpage related files to a web view in my android application. I tried loading the webpage main html file(index.html) into the web view and it successfully loads. But the problem arises at the part where the other assets(like css files, images, js files) are not making it look like it should. Only the html part is loaded while other are left behind.
This is the output how is it looking like

[image: 1]

Instead it should look like this
[image: 2]

The rest of the assets files are not getting linked. Can anyone help?

Here the link is my Html source Code:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1upMVriZoXuBVlmTXSqjN0EVY9O48T9sEnXOpToLW4CQ/edit
```

Comment: Show your html source.

Comment: I have edited the information above @blackapps

Comment: I asked to post the relevant lines of your html source here.

Comment: I will explain you the whole thing. I have a button in an activity, which when clicked prompts me to select the html file from my device and when it selects the file the file gets loaded to the Url using the loadUrl(PATH OF FILE). Now, exactly which relevant lines you want where linking is happing or what? @blackapps

Comment: Unbelievable: `But the problem arises at the part where the other assets(like css files, images, js files) are not making it look like it should. Only the html part is loaded while other are left behind.`

Comment: I added the screenshots. My files are stored in the sdcard. Location: sdcard>Assets>Files and other assests

Comment: `sdcard>Assets>Files` That is an impossible path to begin with. Further you should show the html source that tries to load those files. Third time i ask.

Comment: My Assets contains: index.html(Main File), contact.html, service.html and asset( which css files, images, js files.